# Italian characters in android

Tags: android

I just got my app strings translated to italian but having issues in displaying them on android device.
For example, one of the word is "velocità", on the device the last character à is shown as junk character.

Any pointers on how can I resolve it. The above word is present in the raw-it folder in a .txt file.

Comment: You do know you don't have to create your own text file translation system? http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have the txt file not encoded as utf-8. Right click on the file in Eclipse and then properties. Set it to UTF-8. (You might need to copy the text into it again to make the characters appear ok).

Answer (score 0):

UTF8 encoding supports foreign language characters. Try using UTF8 encoding. if that doesnt work then the problemmight be because of the font used.Good Luck.